# Swapping functions of Back and Menu hardware buttons on Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, hardware, buttons, user-interface

Samsung reverses the position of Android's *Back* and *Menu* (aka *Options*) buttons, when compared to almost every other device.

How does one swap the functionality of these hardware buttons, specifically on the Samsung Galaxy S4?

Fortunately, the hardware buttons have no visual indication of the pre-programmed functionality if the user turns off the LED lights for those buttons.  Thus, swapping them so the *Back* button is on the left should be transparent to the user.

Root and Xposed solutions are fine, if required.

Comment: What is Options' button? Can you provide a screenshot? Have you tried [Xposed Additions](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spazedog.xposed.additionsgb&hl=en)?

Comment: @Firelord "options" button means the "menu" button here. Pre-KK devices had such a soft button. While on most devices, "back" is the right-most and "menu" the left-most button, indeed Samsung devices have that inverted. Confuses me each time someone hands me one (I always hit the wrong button first :)

Comment: @Firelord LOL.  Izzy is correct.  I always called it the *Menu* button, but others kept correcting me claiming it's called the *Options* button, so that's the terminology I originally used in this question.  I'll edit the question to use both terms. :-)